# Python Hashtable linear probing

Tags: python, hashtable, counter, linear-probing

I am trying to find which index in a given list would give the largest number of probes needed before that index is assigned in a hashtable. I have a list which looks something like this:

[4, 9, 12, 3, 7, 26, 16, 20, 11]

and i need to figure out which values in that list creates the longest probe sequence. I've been stuck on this for quite a while now and any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: how big is your hashtable

Comment: What is your final goal?

Comment: The hashtable for this example is 13

Comment: I need to return the index positions in the hashtable that gives the longest probing sequence